# Select By NULL values in DAS Stream

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, siddhi

I have a stream with multiple attributes. Lets assume name of the stream is "**MyStream**" and it is imported to the execution plan as "**my**". Names of attributes are "**A**" and "**B**".   "**B**" attribute can have **NULL** values. I want to select Both "**A**" and "**B**" where "**B**" is **NULL**. I try Bellow code.

```
FROM my[B is null]      
SELECT A as A,B as B
INSERT INTO out;
```

But the "**out**" stream is always empty. "**B**"s data type is **FLOAT**. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Actually i just wanted to assign a value to "B" where B is default "NULL"

Answer (score 1):

I try bellow code and it worked for me.

```
FROM my      
SELECT A as A,
       ifThenElse(B is null,convert(0.1,'FOLAT'),B) as B
INSERT INTO out;
```